# Is there a canonical syntax for parameter types in roxygen?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I use R with Roxygen. There you have `@param` blocks just like in Doxygen and JavaDoc. Since R is dynamically typed (duck-typed even), there is no type information as there is with C++ or Java. For PHP and Python I have seen that one can use `@param int $n` in PHPDoc and `:param int n:` with Sphinx (for Python).

Roxygen seems to lack this feature and the various style guides just say something about describing the type (in English). Is there some canonical or at least sensible way to standardize this?

I would like to have information like the following:

- Type of class `myClass`
- Numeric vector of length 3
- Named list which each has certain fields

Perhaps using

```
@param x A named list with fields "a", "b", and "c" which are logical. 
    These selects whether the three methods are to be used.
```

or rather

```
@param x Selectors for the methods "a", "b", and "c".
    (Named list of logical).
```

Abstractly there are many possibilities:

- Type: Description.
- Description. Type.
- (Type) Description.
- …

In Doxygen and PHPDoc I get a third column (parameter name, type, description) but here I have to do with just two columns. Can this be solved sensibly in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's a universally agreed standard, but one option would be to follow the syntax generated by roxygen when describing objects that a package makes available via `data()`.

For instance, if your package's contains a file `data/myList.R` that contains the object

```
myList <- list (A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4)
```

then this item might minimally be documented in `R/data.R` using the roxygen syntax

```
#' My List
#' @keywords datasets
"myList"
```

roxygen will then automatically document the object's format as

> An object of class `list` of length 4.

This structure seems like an obvious syntax to follow when describing parameters, too, though this would have to be done manually.  A generic solution is perhaps unattainable, as some functions can handle parameters with all sorts of properties and classes.